# Redirecting two pages from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: .htaccess, https, redirect

I have two pages I need to redirect from HTTPS to HTTP. I have working code for a single page but I am struggling to figure out how to get it working for two pages.

It redirects request to /modules/gateways/callback/pne.php

I need it to also do requests to /modules/gateways/callback/two.php

Simply duplicating the same code below it causes a redirect loop it seems.

```html
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/modules/gateways/callback/one\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(modules/gateways/callback/one\.php)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was a simple as removing the first rule, as I actually don't need all other requests auto redirected.

This is the final code.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(modules/gateways/callback/one\.php)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(modules/gateways/callback/two\.php)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```